# Incorrectly operating collision

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have **Player** Object with `BoxCollider2D` and `RigidBody2D` (standard settings)

I still have **Another** Object with `BoxCollider2D` and `RigidBody2D` (standard settings)

When **Player** jumps onto this object, he stops on it and you can see that Collider worked. But when I go horizontally it passes by the object.

The `OnCollisionEnter2D` method is called

What could be the reason?

Comment: please share more detailed information..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem.

Reason for the problem:

- When moving an object out of code, physics has no effect on these objects. I made a workaround in the code.

I include the code for the simplified character controller:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewPlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 startPosition = Vector2.zero;
    private bool onlyLeftMovement = false;
    private bool onlyRightMovement = false;

    public float jumpHeight = 2f;
    public float playerSpeed = 4f;

    void Start()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void AddMovement(float moveHorizontal)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + (moveHorizontal * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed), transform.position.y);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (onlyLeftMovement)
        {
            if (moveHorizontal <= 0) AddMovement(moveHorizontal);
        }
        else if (onlyRightMovement)
        {
            if (moveHorizontal >= 0) AddMovement(moveHorizontal);
        }
        else AddMovement(moveHorizontal);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "MyObjectTag")
        {
            if (transform.position.x < collision.gameObject.transform.position.x)
            {
                // Only left direction
                onlyLeftMovement = true;
                onlyRightMovement = false;
            }
            else if (transform.position.x > collision.gameObject.transform.position.x)
            {
                // Only right direction
                onlyLeftMovement = false;
                onlyRightMovement = true;
            }

            if (transform.position.y > (startPosition.y + jumpHeight / 10))
            {
                // Every direction
                onlyLeftMovement = false;
                onlyRightMovement = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "MyObjectTag")
        {
            onlyLeftMovement = false;
            onlyRightMovement = false;
        }
    }
}
```